# JSON.NET deserializing a multidimensional array?

Tags: json, list, multidimensional-array, json.net, deserialization

I am passing (or well trying to!) a JSON object to my codebehind.

This is the JSON object:

```
[
    {
        "testLaag":{
            "layer_zindex":1,
            "layer_type":1,
            "layer_width":1,
            "layer_height":1,
            "layer_offset_left":1,
            "layer_offset_top":1,
            "layer_html":1,
            "layer_fontcolor":1,
            "layer_fontsize":1,
            "layer_rotation":1,
            "layer_color":1,
            "layer_name":1,
            "layer_fontFamily":1
        },
        "testLaag2":{
            "layer_zindex":2,
            "layer_type":2,
            "layer_width":2,
            "layer_height":2,
            "layer_offset_left":2,
            "layer_offset_top":2,
            "layer_html":2,
            "layer_fontcolor":2,
            "layer_fontsize":2,
            "layer_rotation":2,
            "layer_color":2,
            "layer_name":2,
            "layer_fontFamily":2
        }
    }
]
```

The code from the code behind:

```
string data = "[" + Request.Form["layers"] + "]";
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
List<Laag> layers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Laag>>(data, settings);

foreach (Laag laag in layers)
{
    Response.Write(laag.layer_name);
}
```

And here is my class:

```
public class Laag
{
    public int layer_zindex {get; set;}
    public int layer_type { get; set; }    
    public double layer_width { get; set; }
    public double layer_height { get; set; }
    public double layer_offset_left { get; set; }
    public double layer_offset_top { get; set; }
    public string layer_html { get; set; }
    public string layer_fontcolor { get; set; }
    public double layer_fontsize { get; set; }
    public double layer_rotation { get; set; }
    public string layer_color { get; set; }
    public string layer_name { get; set; }
    public string layer_fontFamily { get; set; }
}
```

It is currently driving both me and my colleague nuts. All we want, is to have both "laag" objects in a List object. JSON and how to process are quite new to both of us, so we're probably missing something incredibly stupid though.

Thanks in advance,

-Ferdy

Answer (score 1):

Create another wrapper class

```
public class wrapperOfLaag{
     public List<Laag> listLag;
}
```

and then try

```
string data = "[" + Request.Form["layers"] + "]";
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
wrapperOfLaag p = ser.Deserialize<wrapperOfLaag >(data);
```